# Cassandra many tables vs lots of secondary key lookups

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I need to store posts in a community and each post has comments.

-Assume I only regenerate the post pages that contain comments infrequently, hourly at first for a day and then monthly or yearly. This means reading is infrequent, but when I read I potentially perform thousands of reads all at once to regenerate the page.

Which strategy is correct? 
(1) Have a table for each post which contains all the comments, this means I could potentially have millions of tables in a keyspace if I get millions of posts. But all the comments will be easily query-able and sort-able.

(2) Have a table for all posts and another table for all comments. I'll have to use a secondary key to denote which post a comment is linked to which seems slow if I need to lookup thousands of comments to generate a post page. This slower performance may be okay since I use a periodically regenerated static page system though.

I expect (2) is the correct "Cassandra" way of doing this, but (1) does seem tempting if the overhead of each table isn't too-high or can be loaded into memory only when a post needs to be regenerated.

EDIT:
After chatting with people in the Cassandra Slack it seems my only option is (2) because of memory overhead. So my question now stands:

If I have a billion comments, 10,000 per post, and I need to find those 10,000 in the haystack of the billion total comments, is this feasible performance wise?

Answer (score 1):

you should have a table for all of your posts and another table for comments per posts.

```
comments_by_posts
   post_id   uuid
   comment_id   uuid
   comment   text
   .....
   primary key ((post_id), comment_id)
```

post_id will be your partition key, and comment_id will be your clustering key. Together they will be the primary key of your table.

Since post_id is your partition key, reads will be based on the post_id and ordered by your comment_id. Finding 10000 comments for a post will be still really easy and fast. Because they will be in the same partition.